# Setup MySQL replication with VMware client and host

Tags: mysql, replication, vmware

I have a laptop running Windows 8.1 64bit. What i plan to do is to install mysql server. and then i would install Windows 7 32 bit on a VMWare on the same laptop and will also have mysql server plus bridged networking so it will have different ip with the host OS.

so basically i will have a laptop running windows 8.1 64 bit with mysql server installed. With a vmware running windows 7 32 bit which also have mysql server installed.

Next, i want to set up the mysql server on the windows 8.1 as a master and setup the mysql server on the vmware (running windows 7 32 bit) as a slave.

My question is, will this work? I don't want to start configuring because it will take a lot of time.

If it is not achievable, can somebody recommend me a way to demonstrate mysql replication using only a single laptop/computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. It will work. Make shure both sysem can ping each other (being in same subnet) But you should configure it only for demonstration. The other case it has no sence.